# Apache Drill JDBC connectivity through java code is giving error:Failure in connecting to Drill: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException

Tags: jdbc, apache-drill

i am trying drill-jdbc connectivity through java code.

Error is:-

**java.sql.SQLException: Failure in connecting to Drill: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:31010**

So the steps followed are below:-

1. wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/drill/drill-1.12.0/apache-drill-1.12.0.tar.gz
2. tar -xvf apache-drill-1.12.0.tar.gz
3. cd apache-drill-1.12.0
4. cd bin
5. ./drillbit.sh start -Ddrill.exec.http.port=8765
6. To check check its running under zookeeeper
7. cd /usr/hdp/current/zookeeper-client
8. ./zkCli.sh
9. ls /drill
10. In apache-drill-1.12.0/bin
11. started drill-localhost # ./drill-localhost
    received contents "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0 apache drill 1.12.0"
    normal database queries were working properly

**is there any dependancy between jdk -version?**

Java Code:-

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DrillJDBCExample {
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost:";//"jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181";
//"jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost";


static final String USER = "admin";
static final String PASS = "admin";


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  /*    Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:drillbit=127.0.0.1:8765");
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from cp.`employee`");
    while(rs.next()){
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
}*/
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);


        stmt = conn.createStatement();
       //  Perform a select on data in the classpath storage plugin. 
        String sql = "select employee_id,first_name,last_name from cp.`employee.json`";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


        while(rs.next()) {
            int id  = rs.getInt("employee_id");
            String first = rs.getString("first_name");
            String last = rs.getString("last_name");


            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", First: " + first);
            System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
        }


        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch(SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{
            if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch(SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

**Error Logs:-**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in connecting to Drill: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: HANDSHAKE_COMMUNICATION : Channel closed /127.0.0.1:60181 <--> localhost/127.0.0.1:8765.
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:162)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
at oadd.net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.mapr.drill.DrillJDBCExample.main(DrillJDBCExample.java:29)
Caused by: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: HANDSHAKE_COMMUNICATION : Channel closed /127.0.0.1:60181 <--> localhost/127.0.0.1:8765.
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient$FutureHandler.connectionFailed(DrillClient.java:675)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.QueryResultHandler$ChannelClosedHandler.connectionFailed(QueryResultHandler.java:389)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$HandshakeSendHandler.failed(BasicClient.java:254)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RequestIdMap$RpcListener.setException(RequestIdMap.java:134)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RequestIdMap$SetExceptionProcedure.apply(RequestIdMap.java:74)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RequestIdMap$SetExceptionProcedure.apply(RequestIdMap.java:64)
at oadd.com.carrotsearch.hppc.IntObjectHashMap.forEach(IntObjectHashMap.java:692)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RequestIdMap.channelClosed(RequestIdMap.java:58)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RemoteConnection.channelClosed(RemoteConnection.java:175)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcBus$ChannelClosedHandler.operationComplete(RpcBus.java:167)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcBus$ChannelClosedHandler.operationComplete(RpcBus.java:146)
at oadd.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
at oadd.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:567)
at oadd.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:406)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:943)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:592)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:584)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1099)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:615)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.close(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:71)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:615)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.close(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:73)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:615)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:466)
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcExceptionHandler.exceptionCaught(RpcExceptionHandler.java:39)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:79)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:253)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:809)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
at oadd.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:242)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:339)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:847)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at oadd.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at oadd.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.ChannelClosedException: Channel closed /127.0.0.1:60181 <--> localhost/127.0.0.1:8765.
at oadd.org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcBus$ChannelClosedHandler.operationComplete(RpcBus.java:166)
... 52 more
```

Followed documents are:-

1) https://drill.apache.org/docs/

2) https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/10551/apache-drill-unofficial-introduction.html

Comment: This might be more of an issue for a Jira bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/DRILL/issues/?filter=allopenissues

Comment: ok . how to resolve it?

Comment: Well, report it in the Jira, they might be much more able to help. I have never seen this error.

Comment: Not sure why connection goes to  port '8765' which is 'drill.exec.http.port' set as per your start command. It should ideally be connecting to user port '31010'. Are you able to connect using sqlline?

Comment: In the exception it shows connection error for port 31010 but in error logs the exception shows for port 8765. Can you clean and compile your client program once to make sure previous connection URL is not picked ?
Also are you able to connect the WebServer http://localhost:8765 ?